# How to get Thoughtworks Go.CD to trigger pipelines quicker

Tags: go-cd, thoughtworks-go

Go pipelines can sometimes take an age to start after a Git commit and push. Even after manually hitting the start button it can take a long time. Is there a setting or way to get it to pick up changes quicker and start quicker? I don't mind if it uses more resources on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong with out Go Server. Rebuilding a new server solved the problem. It can still take upt to 30 seconds to start a pipeline (it was taking ten minutes).